# Enable 2FA on apt-installed phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apt

I'm trying to enable 2FA on a phpmyadmin version installed via APT. The documentation uses the composer command, but doing it in the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` folder doesn't change anything.

When I go in the 2FA configuration, it always says `Two-factor authentication is not available, please install optional dependencies to enable authentication backends`.

I tried installing `pragmarx/google2fa` and `bacon/bacon-qr-code` both in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/vendor` and in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor` but it still didn't work.

What I'm using:

- phpmyadmin 4.9.5deb2
- Ubuntu 20.04
- nginx 1.18.0
- PHP 7.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported currently, but is still in progress on our tracker: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16779

The alternative is to install phpMyAdmin from the version distributed on the phpMyAdmin website.